# How to calculate $\Pr[\max(X,Y)<4]$?

Tags: probability, statistics, actuarial-science

Suppose the joint PDF of X,Y is $f(x,y)=1/40$ and $0 < x < 5$ and $0 < y < 8$.

How to calculate $\Pr[\max(X,Y)<4]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$
P(\max(X,Y)<4)=P(X<4,Y<4)=P((X,Y)\in (-\infty,4)\times(-\infty,4)).
$$

Comment: OK thanks I got it